# Multiple Image is not calling in canvas using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js framework. I am working on two canvas. Below is the code

```
<canvas id="drawing-area1" width="400" height="475" class="upper-canvas" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;cursor: default;"></canvas>

<canvas id="drawing-area1_a1" width="400" height="475" class="upper-canvas" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-user-select: none;cursor: default;"></canvas>
```

Below are my js

```
window["canvas"] = window.__canvas = new fabric.Element('drawing-area1',{backgroundColor : "#cccccc",selection: false,backgroundImage:$('#imageimage1').val() })}


window["canvas_a"] = window.__canvas = new fabric.Element('drawing-area1_a1',{backgroundColor : "#cccccc",selection: false,backgroundImage:$('#imageimage1').val() })}
```

Only the first canvas works while the other canvas does not shows any image. I really dont know how to use multiple canvas. I googled it but still no luck.